# Rails Capstrano rvm method_missing

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, amazon-web-services, passenger, web-deployment

I want to deploy Rails app to AWS EC2 by using `capstrano`, but after I type `cap production deploy`, I found following error in console.

```
DEBUG [309bdf2a] Command: cd /home/ubuntu/MY_APP/releases/20161203071428 && ~/.rvm/bin/rvm 2.3.1@rails5.0.0.1 do passenger -v

DEBUG [309bdf2a]    /home/ubuntu/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.1/lib/ruby/2.3.0/rubygems/specification.rb:2158:in `method_missing'

DEBUG [309bdf2a]    undefined method `this' for #<Gem::Specification:0x9b54b0 passenger-5.0.30>
```

I thought the problem is cause by `rvm` or `passenger`, but I am not sure is it the problem of permission or path.

Here is the setting in **deploy/production.rb**

```
set :rvm_type, :auto
set :rvm_ruby_version, '2.3.1@rails5.0.0.1'
set :passenger_rvm_ruby_versionw
```

I also put the following code in in the **Capfile**.

```
require 'capistrano/rvm'
require 'capistrano/bundler'
require 'capistrano/rails/assets'
require 'capistrano/rails/migrations'
require 'capistrano/puma'
require 'capistrano/passenger'
```

If you need more information, please let me know!

Here is the whole error message

https://gist.github.com/fifiteen82726/62cc9ce9a5c00778c2bff76e3fb59b9a

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a lot of searching, I found out there are some bugs in gem version 2.5.1.

According to this [Issue](https://github.com/remomueller/documentation/issues/7), this is fixed with the [RubyGems 2.6.3](https://rubygems.org/gems/rubygems-update/versions/2.6.3)

So, what I did is updating my gem version.

I typed the following command.

```
gem install rubygems-update -v 2.6.3
update_rubygems
gem update --system
```

And then rerun `cap production deploy`. Everything is fine.